# faster way to grab previous data before update query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am about to run a mysql update query to update information in the database. My goal is to grab the previous data before it is updated and store it in a variable before it get's updated.

Is there a faster way to do it without performing 2 queries?

```
//grab previous time
$grab_previous_time = $dbg->prepare("SELECT timestamp FROM form WHERE id = :id");
$grab_previous_time->(array(':id' => $id));

$previous_time = $grab_previous_time->fetchColumn();
$previous_time = $previous_time['timestamp'];

//Update data
$update_form = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE `form` SET `timestamp` = :time WHERE id = :id");
$update_form->execute(array(':time' => $time, ':id' => $id));
```

Comment: faster than? have you benchmarked how fast it is already?

Comment: I guess I am fully unaware @Dagon but thank you for clarifying

Comment: people are always asking for the fastest way to do X with out knowing how fast their current approach is, or if speed is an issue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dagon pointed out that there is nothing un-usual about my queries and that speed shouldn't be an issue with what I am doing.

Answer (score -1):

No, the only solution is the one you describe.

Comment: me, its wrong, there are several other ways, triggers and  stored procedures to name two

Comment: A trigger can't return the information to the calling script, all it could do is store the previous data somewhere else.

Comment: And the stored procedure doesn't bring any benefit over executing a simple SELECT statement.